# Is there a way to link two same-models in Prisma, guaranteeing each position against a row type

Tags: prisma

I have a User model with a Role attribute of either Student, Guardian or Staff.

I have an Associations linking model with studentId, guardianId, relationshipType.
*studentId and guardianId both refer to User ID above.*

Is there any way to enforce studentId is a user with a role of Student and guardianId is a User with a role of Guardian?

Currently I am using a separate Student/Guardian model pointing to the general User model to link the 2, which works, but makes retrieving information from the User model difficult. For example, I want to find a student's guardian:

I have to query User and make sure to include Student relation with an even deeper nested Associations. Now I can get the guardianId, and run a query on the Guardian Model. (Since I don't have easy access to deeply nested Associations) Now I need to find the User upstream of Guardian to get the user's first name. It gets even more complicated if I need to access something deeply nested on the User model.  I have made this easier by ensuring PK of both User, Student and Guardian are all the same, but it still feels awkward.

Any other suggestions are welcome!